# Rx .NET mark an event as handled or pass by reference

Tags: .net-core, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I have a simple event bus to fire Rx events:

```cs
public class EventBus
{
    private readonly LayerStack _layerStack;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Subject<IEvent>> _subjects = new ();

    public EventBus(LayerStack layerStack) => _layerStack = layerStack;

    public void Publish<T>(T @event) where T : IEvent
    {
        foreach (var layer in _layerStack.Layers)
            if (_subjects.TryGetValue(layer, out var subject))
                subject.OnNext(@event);
    }

    public IObservable<T> AsObservable<T>() where T : IEvent => GetLayerSubject().OfType<T>().Where(e => !e.Handled);
    public IDisposable Subscribe<T>(Action<T> action) where T : IEvent => GetLayerSubject().OfType<T>().Where(e => !e.Handled).Subscribe(action);
    public IDisposable Subscribe<T>(IObserver<T> observer) where T : IEvent => GetLayerSubject().OfType<T>().Where(e => !e.Handled).Subscribe(observer);

    private ISubject<IEvent> GetLayerSubject()
    {
        var layer = new StackFrame(2).GetMethod()!.DeclaringType!.Name;
        if (!_subjects.ContainsKey(layer))
            _subjects.AddOrUpdate(layer, new Subject<IEvent>(), (l, s) => _subjects[l] = s);

        return _subjects[layer];
    }
}
```

I am using a Stack to propagate events through layers in the stack to ensure ordering of events through system layers but just updating the `Handled` property is doing nothing to the original event. Is there some way to pass these events by reference instead?

Consuming code:

```cs
public class CoreLayer // will be in first layer
{
    public CoreLayer(ILogger<CoreLayer> logger, EventBus events)
    {
        events.Subscribe<WindowOpenedEvent>(e =>
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            logger.LogInformation("{Event}", e.ToString()); // Should run
        });
    }
}

public class UILayer // will be in second layer
{
    public UILayer (ILogger<UILayer> logger, EventBus events)
    {
        events.Subscribe<WindowOpenedEvent>(e =>
        {
            logger.LogInformation("{Event}", e.ToString()); // Shouldn't run
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was using structs with interfaces, I switched to classes for the events and an abstract Event class and it works as intended.

Comment: I would use composition here and put an `IEventEnvelope` around your data and use to to indicate if it was handled or not. Then you can still retain the value type.

Comment: @Enigmativity could you give a code representation of what you mean? I'm assuming you mean add an interface to the event giving it the `Handled` property but I can't see how that would change what was happening when I was subscribing to events and setting the handled property. I would ideally prefer to be dealing with readonly ref structs where possible.

Comment: I'm suggesting doing something like this: `public interface IEventEnvelope<T> where T : struct { bool Handled { get; } T Event { get; } }`.

Comment: @Enigmativity https://dotnetfiddle.net/MPYXil is the simplest version of what I'm doing, could you show me how you imagine this working?

Comment: The same thing using structs/interface - https://dotnetfiddle.net/6glSGd

Comment: I changed the interface `Handled` to be a ref bool and the added a `private static bool _handled` to the struct which stops the defensive copy of the struct property and allows me to change the actual value (https://dotnetfiddle.net/r7bIYl)